# PHP connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Sorry for a such beginner questions, but I just started to learn PHP.

My code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = 'XXXXXXXX';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I set the password in my.ini file:
[image]

But I get an error message:
[image]

It shows, that the problem is in line 11, but I cant figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The file my.ini doesn’t define the password inside the server. You’ll have to set up the user in the server properly.

Comment: But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first ,get into mysql, then exec

```
grant all privileges on *.* to user@localhost identified by 'password';
flush privileges;
```

replace user and password as you want

Comment: And don't forget to restart MySQL service (in xampp console, for example)

Comment: there is no need to restart mysql after exec `flush privileges;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't set your user/pass in your my.ini file.  You also probably shouldn't be logging into your You do it via SQL. See the following:
[Creating accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-users.html)

You also probably shouldn't be logging into your MySQL via php as `root` either, this is why you should create a unique user for this purpose.